# Latex matrix of real numbers R^3x3

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I trying to write R^3x3 (for a matrix 3 columns and 3 rows) in Latex using this:

```
 \mathbb{R}^3x3
```

But all this does is put the first 3 in the power and then writes x3 next to it in normal text.I must be searching wrong on google, so I can't find it.

Also tried some stuff like:

```
\mathbb{R}^(3x3)
or
\mathbb{R}^[3x3]
```

But this gives nothing

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `\mathbb{R}^{3x3}`?

Comment: just tried it a minute ago was going to tell that I found it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You should put `3x3` in `{}` like:

```
$\mathbb{R}^{3x3}$
```

or better

```
$\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$
```